# Causing a 3 row GridView to fill the available vertical space?

Tags: android, gridview

I have a two column, three row GridView that I would like to have fill the available screen space provided by the surrounding layouts. By setting the layout_height and layout_width to "fill_parent" and the background color to red I can see that the GridView is in fact filling the space -- but the content is not.

When there is extra space, I'd like the GridView to have more verticalSpacing or horizontalSpacing to "fill up" the screen. I don't see an available setting to do that though.

There has to be an elegant way to do this, but I've yet to find it =\

Comment: "There has to be an elegant way to do this, but I've yet to find it" -- I doubt it. `GridView` is designed to handle having more cells than the available space can hold, not to handle your case. I would not be the least bit surprised if you had to implement your own `AdapterView`, or at least clone `GridView` and substantially modify it, to achieve your aims.

Comment: I'll look into the AdapterView implementation this afternoon. I appreciate the quick response!